# Query (SQL like joins) remote CSV for data analysis

Tags: csv, data-analysis, presto

I would like to query (SQL with joins) CSV files sitting in a network folder for performing data analysis work. I'm not allowed to move the files out of the network folder due to regulatory reasons. Obviously, I also cannot import the CSV into a database table.

I'm beginning to explore **Presto** for this, but I'm not sure if it can handle this scenario. Any advise from Presto experts?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SQLite https://www.sqlite.org/index.html

SQLite is *NOT* a "regular" client-server DB, it it a **local file** DB (or even in RAM memory if you want) that stores all you data. Using this your data never leaves your network folder.

You can easily import the CSV file into that local DB (doing an import to real table or [virtual table](https://www.sqlite.org/csv.html))

Comment: I'm not allowed to move the data (CSV files) out of the network folder into any database. I need something that can directly query the remote CSV files without having to load elsewhere.

Comment: @museshad this exactly what SQLite does - all the files and queries are done on that remote folder..